# CiviMail doesn't save when using Checksum event links

Tags: civimail, checksum

Running CiviCRM 5.10.4 and Drupal 7.65.

Trying to send out a bulk email through CiviMail using a checksum link for an event registration.

However when I insert the checksum link, I get an error message when CiviMail tries to autosave, or when I try to manually save:

```
Sorry an error occurred and your information was not saved
```

This is the checksum link I'm trying to insert

```
https://DOMAIN.com/civicrm/event/register?reset=1&id=89&cid={contact.contact_id}&{contact.checksum}
```

I've also tried with:

```
https://DOMAIN.com/civicrm/event/register?reset=1&id=89&{contact.checksum}&cid={contact.contact_id}
```

Have tried testing to save with every move I make when making the email, and have isolated the issue to only happening when I try to use these links (whether it's an image linked to this URL, or text).

I've checked and that is the correct event ID in the URL. I've tried inserting the link in the source code and in the WYSIWYG editor but neither are allowing me to save. I've tried writing out the URL in notepad and copying over from there in case any formatting is being pulled through somehow, but again no luck.

Any idea on where we're going wrong or how to fix this?

Cheers

EDIT: On more investigation, it allows me to save the email when I use the following link. However this creates an extra "cs=" in the URL so the checksums don't work....

The URL I've used this time is:

```
https://DOMAIN.com/civicrm/event/register?reset=1&id=89&cid={contact.contact_id}&cs={contact.checksum}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org. Are you able to reproduce the error there?

Comment: @Demerit I wasn't able to reproduce it on that demo site either

Comment: Is upgrading an option for you? Are you able to test an upgrade on a copy of the site?

Comment: @Demerit do you mean upgrading to a newer version of CiviCRM? I've generally only been updating when a security update is necessary - but can give that a go as well.

Comment: Yes a newer vision of civi, since if it's not happening on the demo maybe upgrading will fix it by itself.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this exact same problem.  (I'm on Version 5.25.0, posting over a year later, so an upgrade would not have been the answer)

What "fixed" my problem was to change the order of the parameters so that the checksum parameter was first after the ?

[https://DOMAIN.com/WEBFORM?{contact.checksum}&cid1={contact.contact_id}](https://DOMAIN.com/WEBFORM?%7Bcontact.checksum%7D&cid1=%7Bcontact.contact_id%7D)

instead of:

[https://DOMAIN.com/WEBFORM?cid1={contact.contact_id}&{contact.checksum}](https://DOMAIN.com/WEBFORM?cid1=%7Bcontact.contact_id%7D&%7Bcontact.checksum%7D)

It is odd that the checksum token inserts "cs=" before it, which breaks the URL validation.